# 'Message' object has no attribute 'chat_id'

Tags: python, telebot

```py
from http import client
import telebot
import configg

client = telebot.TeleBot(configg.config['token']) 
#<------------------обработка полученных сообщений пользователя----------------->
@client.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def get_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет' :
        client.send_message(message.chat.id , 'Привет неизвестный пользователь')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'как дела?' :
        client.send_message(message.chat.id , 'пойдет, у тебя как?')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'какая погода?' :
        client.send_message(message.chat.id , 'ну вроде жить можно :)')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'как дома?' :
        client.send_message(message.chat.id , 'температура в доме +18 градусов \ кот спит')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'фото' :
        # client.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo = 'https://clck.ru/bJ849', caption = 'foto') 
        pic = 'https://penzavzglyad.ru/images/uploads/2021/03/11/88db2b6320f164d39b27d80aac3b6551.jpg'
        client.send_photo(message.chat_id, pic)
#<------------------обработка полученных сообщений пользователя----------------->
# -----------------------------------------------------------
client.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
File "c:\Users\felix\Desktop\sendFotoBot\sendFotoBot.py", line 34, in <module>
    client.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0) 

  File "C:\Users\felix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 658, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)

  File "C:\Users\felix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 720, in __threaded_polling
    raise e

  File "C:\Users\felix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 680, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()


  File "C:\Users\felix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 135, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info

  File "C:\Users\felix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 87, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)

  File "c:\Users\felix\Desktop\sendFotoBot\sendFotoBot.py", line 23, in get_text
    client.send_photo(message.chat_id, pic)
***AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'chat_id'***
```

Comment: Почему вы в других местах используете `message.chat.id`, а конкретно здесь решили использовать `message.chat_id`?

Comment: Извините, но я не понял вопроса. Я использовал message.chat.id в случае отправки пользователю чего-либо: фото или сообщений. message.chat.id следует же всегда его указывать его при отправке чего-либо. :)

Comment: Перечитайте ваш код внимательно, вы вместо этого использовали message.chat_id